How do I find the wavelength of an EM wave derived from an accelerating electron, given its acceleration?
I understand the Larmors formula, but I can't find any material regarding wavelength of a single photon.

Liénard–Wiechert potential

The Larmor formula gives the Poynting power of radiation coming off a classical charged particle in accelerated motion. It does not give distribution of frequencies in this radiation. Acceleration alone does not determine this spectrum; we need more information on the motion (velocity, position).
When the charged particle moves in circles in a cyclotron or synchrotron, its field is a series of directional pulses at the base frequency, and for such radiation, there are formulae for power spectra - intensities of each frequency. Such power spectrum is a dense comb of peaks at harmonic frequencies, with varying envelope.
For a discussion of power spectrum of a single electron in synchrotron motion, see e.g. the section 5.3.1 here:
https://www.cv.nrao.edu/~sransom/web/Ch5.html

1/2.   I understand the process of photon emission in a magnetic field in such a way that the electron is subject to subsequent lateral deflection with each photon emission. At the same time, it slows down. The circular motion is therefore not circular in two ways. Firstly, the electron slows down and its path is a spiral (at the end of which it has exhausted its kinetic energy) and this spiral is actually a sequence of trajectories that have the shape of adjacent tangerine slices.

2/2. For each "tangerine" piece, it should be possible to determine the frequency of the emitted photon from the strength of the magnetic field and the instantaneous speed of the electron. Or can several photons be emitted during the "tangerine" cycle?

@HolgerFiedler in a consistent classical theory where the electron moving in magnetic field is a point and has a trajectory, it is not possible to also have the photon idea. Emission or absorption of energy quantum by the electron would mean that in its rest frame, where kinetic energy is zero, electron's rest energy (and thus, mass) changes. But such change of mass was never detected. Electron does not (usually, when interacting with EM field of other particles) lose mass.
